# Apache http server one instance per Virtual host

Tags: apache, memory, virtualhost, httpserver

I was interested in working with apache http server based on next parameters:

1. On a single server running listenin in one single port
2. Having condigured several Virtualhosts, one per domain
3. running each Virtualhost as an instance listening in por 80
4. been able to reload one domain configuration without having to restart the rest.

I have doubts about the memory consumption and if there's, how should i improve it.

- I don't think that would be a memory problem (correct me if I'm wrong) as soon as there's only one http server running?
- or maybe yes because each instance comsumes independent memory?
- should be same memory compsumption as running all the VirtuallHosts on the main apache config file?

Many thanks, I mainly want to run one instance per domain because I want to be able to restart each VirtualHost configuration when is needed without having to restart the others.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

First I don't think you can run several apache instance if they are all listening to port 80. **Only one process can bind the port**.

Apache will have several child processes, all child of the process listenign on port 80, but each child process can be used for any VirtualHost.

You could achieve it by binding different IP on port 80, so having **IP based VirtualHosts**. Or by using one Apache as a proxy for other Apache instances binded on other ports.

But the restart problem is not a real problem. Apache can perform safe-restart (reload on some distributions) where each child process is reloaded after the end of his running job. So it's a **transparent restart**, without any HTTP request killed. Adding or removing a VirtualHost does not need a restart, a simple reload is enought.

Answer (score 0):

I have to think there are ways of achieving what you want without individual instances.  Seriously large virtual hosting companies use apache, I am hard pressed to believe your needs are more complex than theirs.  Example: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

Maybe you should run two apache servers to do a rolling restart when it is really needed, which would prevent any individual site from being down as well.